# Add all not tracked files at once

Tags: mercurial

```
$ hg status

M ...
M ...
M ...
? ...
? ...
? ...
```

I need to add all not tracked (? marked) files.  Is it possible?
I can do "hg add *" but I will get many messages unwanted 'file already tracked'.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Just use `hg add` with no `*`.

When no files are given, it adds all untracked files, that is, all files with `?` in front of the output of `hg status`.

Files that are ignored because of `.hgignore` will not be added by `hg add` without filenames.